# Iterates of analytic functions and fixed points

Tags: cv.complex-variables

My question grew from the following $1-$dimensional result.

Let $A,B\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open connected neighbourhoods of $0\in\mathbb{C}$ and $U:A\times B\to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Further, assume that analytic functions $u_n:A\to B$ satisfy iterative scheme
$$
u_0(x)=0, \ u_n(x)=U(x,u_{n-1}(x))x
$$
and $u_n\to v$ uniformly on every compact $L\subset A.$ Then $v(A)\subset B$ and $v$ is a unique analytic solution of the equation $v(x)=U(x,v(x))x$ in $A.$

Can this be generalized to the multidimensional case? Namely, let  $U:A\times B\to \mathbb{C}^{p\times p}$ be an analytic matrix-valued function, defined in an open connected neighbourhood of $(0,0)\in \mathbb{C}^{2p}$ and let analytic functions $u_n:A\to B$ satisfy same relations and converge (uniformly on every compact) to a function $v:A\to\mathbb{C}^p.$

Can one conlcude that $v(A)\subset B$ (in this case $v$ would be a unique analytic solution of the equation $v(x)=U(x,v(x))\cdot x$ in $A$)?

My $1-$dimensional proof does not work because I use Hurwitz theorem to deduce $v(A)\subset \cup_{n\geq 0}u_n(A)\subset B,$ while its analogue for mappings of $\mathbb{C}^p$ is true under certain conditions on $v$ that I can't check in this problem.